# Can "si etiam" have the same meaning as "etiam si"?

Tags: classical-latin, medieval-latin, conjunction, word-order, style

As is well known, "etiam si" is a Latin conjunction that means "even if." Are there any examples in Classical or Medieval Latin in which reversing the word order and saying "si etiam" preserves the meaning "even if", or does "si etiam" always mean "if also"?

Comment: My first guess is that this would be highly irregular:  Here are some [examples to look at](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=si+etiam),

Answer (score 3):

I could find one example from the Vulgata:

- [1st book of Samuel, 23:23 (Regum I in Vulgata)](http://www.drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=9&ch=23&l=23-#x)

> Vulgata: Considerate et videte omnia latibula ejus, in quibus absconditur : et revertimini ad me ad rem certam, ut vadam vobiscum. **Quod si etiam in terram se abstruserit, perscrutabor eum in cunctis millibus Juda.**
>
> Douay Rheims: Consider and see all his lurking holes, wherein he is bid, and return to me with the certainty of the thing, that I may go with you. **And if be should even go down into the earth to hide himself, I will search him out in all the thousands of Juda.**

There is also this second verse, where I think the meaning is also closer to "even if" than to "also if", but I might be wrong.

- [2nd book of Samuel, 5:2 (Regnum II in Vulgata)](http://www.drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=28&ch=5&l=2-#x)

> Vulgata: Quod si etiam, Vivit Dominus, dixerunt, et hac falso jurabunt.
>
> Douay Rheims: And though they say: The Lord liveth; this also they will swear falsely.

Again, although the latter is not exactly "even if", it's meaning is in my view more or less equivalent to it. For example, the translation "And even if they say "The Lord liveth", this also they will swear falsely" conveys imo a very close meaning.

PS: [Douay Rheims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douay%E2%80%93Rheims_Bible) version is perhaps the most important translation into English of the Vulgata.

Comment: I wonder whether it makes a difference to have *quod* before the *si etiam*. Perhaps it's *quod-si etiam* instead of *quod si-etiam*? I expect *quod* to make a bigger difference than the word order.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Mmm, I'm not sure how I can help with that, as the versions I find online have _quod si etiam_. Are you suggesting the "original" Vulgata had quod-si in it? Where dashes used at that time?

Comment: Dashes were not used; I used them for emphasis. I meant the grouping of the words: Are *quod* and *si* a tighter pair than *si* and *etiam*? The spellings *quodsi* and *sietiam* would not be surprising. Since *quodsi* is so common, it seems likely that the *quod* effects the meaning of *si etiam* significantly.